# MySQL trigger/procedure execution delay

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

Is there a decent way to delay execution of mysql trigger?

```
WHILE @condition = 0
  sleep for awhile

insert into some_table values(NEW.value1, NEW.value2);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since MySQL 5.0.12, you can do this:

```
SELECT SLEEP(<seconds>);
```

The seconds parameter can be in a fraction of a second like .5.

Comment: If you don't want a result set, you can do `DO SLEEP(n)` instead.

Answer (score 6):

```
DO SLEEP(<seconds>);
```

is better. There is no reason to just run `SELECT` statements inside triggers without needing the result set.
If you *really* want to do this you need to do it like here:

```
SET @nothing = (SELECT SLEEP(<seconds>));
```

But I recommend to use `DO`. And don't forget that a trigger is just a single statement per default. If you have more then 1 statement in your trigger you need to use `BEGIN`/`END`:

```
BEGIN
    DO SLEEP(<seconds>);
    UPDATE ...;
END
```

Comment: "You cannot just run select statements inside triggers" please elaborate. This is the first time i'm hearing about this. What if you need data from other tables to make your trigger work?