# MySQL time delay a trigger

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL 5.0.67 can you specify a time delay on a trigger?

For example, change the value of a certain column ten minutes after it has been inserted in to the table.

If this is not possible what can be used to create this functionality?

Comment: Good question. Luckily someone else has the answer for you :)  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949950/mysql-trigger-procedure-execution-delay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [sleep function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_sleep):

```
SELECT SLEEP(600);
```

Comment: mysql is giving me an error when I try to use the sleep function.  ERROR 1415 (0A000): Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger

Comment: Hmmm, try setting the results to a variable that you don't use. Like `SET @nothing = (SELECT SLEEP(600));`. The reason that this isn't working is because triggers are not allowed to return values (because there's nowhere for them to go) and the sleep function returns 0.

Comment: Thanks, that worked in the command line but not in my application(jstl). However I found another way around the problem without using triggers or sleep. Thanks for your time!